How to mock i18n of a component
I am using a 3rd party vue component SomeComponent that implements its own translations.
This is my mount in my test
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { SomeComponent } from '../../some-component'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import lang from '../../lang/en'

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  allowComposition: true,
  messages: lang,
})

const items = [{ home: 'Home', about: 'About' }]

const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
        global: {
          plugins: [i18n],
          components: {
            SomeComponent,
          },
        },
        props: {
          items,
        },
      })

But I get this error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 't')

How can I properly mount SomeComponent without mocking SomeComponent itself and resolve the undefined t error?

" implements its own translations" - in which way? Are you certain that it uses the same vue-i18n instance as you provide? Please, show code that throws the error. If it's public then consider explaining what SomeComponent really is, so it could be examined. There could be a problem with methodology. If this is unit test, you're supposed to mock anything but tested component (MyComponent), so you wouldn't have this problem. For integration/e2e that involve third-party components the environment would be less fragile and error-prone, so there are less reasons to do this with vue/test-utils

@EstusFlask, to simplify, I just said that it's a 3rd party component. It's actually a component in a library/package w/in the organization built by another team. I can't change it, but I have a read-only access to it & is indeed using i18n mostly used for validation msgs, default labels and titles. I FIGURED it out already. It exposes an API/function where I pass my components i18n instance. Never had encountered a library component before that does this, so it never occurred to me that it needs the consumer's i18n instance. The authors could have thrown an error with some hint sigh

So it uses the same vue-i18n as in your project (the package is not duped) but creates its own createI18n instance? Makes some sense but not a conventional thing to do

@EstusFlask, the vue-i18n's version in MyComponent and SomeComponent could possibly be different, so I bet things can fail if they are not compatible. SomeComponent does not create its own instance, hence the issue above TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 't'). It needs MyComponent's i18n instance.

The library where the SomeComponent belongs to exposes a setup function where i18n instance needs to be passed. It has to be called prior to mounting SomeComponent. This could have been easier to debug if there was a proper error message, but there's none.
